# Using built-in "open" python method in pybind11 (C++)?

Tags: python, c++11, python-3.6, pybind11

How do you use basic ("default"/"built-in"; don't need to be imported) python methods in pybind11?
Lists, dictionaries, and some others do have built-in compatibility, but the method I am looking specifically for (open) is not included via an import. I know that a way around it would be to create a python file with a method wrapping "open" and then calling it as you would any imported method, but I would prefer to do it directly in C++ (using pybind) if possible as otherwise that semi-defeats the purpose.

Any assistance/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've been looking for same functionallity. Unfortunately it seems like one should implement it by himself. https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/include/pybind11/iostream.h looks like is a good point to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong. First, built-in names are [importable from `builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) (in Python 3):

```
py::object open = py::module::import("builtins").attr("open");
```

Second, `open` also lives in `io` module so you can also use the following  line that is equivalent to the line above:

```
py::object open = py::module::import("io").attr("open");
```

This is for Python 3, but the last line works for Python 2.7 too.

Comment: The builtin `open` has a different signature from `io.open` on Python 2, though.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you! :D